# Intellij postgres can't create tables even though connected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, postgresql-14

everything is running without any problems and no problems. Also Database connected to the IntelliJ Idea but tables are not creating database

[image]

How can i create tables?

Comment: Could you share more code please ? Do you use an ORM? Or something like Hibernate or Spring Data/JPA ? Maybe you should share your application.properties file ?

Comment: What is the error, what are the steps you taken to create, is there any permission issues? please elaborate